# Handling Button gesture for both single and double click/tap

Tags: event-handling, xamarin.forms, double-click

In Xamarin Forms: I want to be able to detect both click/tap and double-click/tap, and to be able to perform different actions.

That is, when the button is clicked I want to perform `actionA`, and when the button is double-clicked I want to perform `actionB`, and only `actionB`.

Comment: For example - > https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/20173/tapgesturerecognizer-using-numberoftapsrequired-for-double-tap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing (kudos to Amit Patil):

```
    private static int clickCount;
    private static object _sender;

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (clickCount < 1)
        {
            TimeSpan tt = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 250);
            _sender = sender;
            Device.StartTimer(tt, ClickHandle);
        }
        clickCount++;
    }

    bool ClickHandle()
    {
        if (clickCount > 1)
        {
            Minus1(_sender);
        }
        else
        {
            Plus1(_sender);
        }
        clickCount = 0;
        _sender = null;
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need an actual button? Else look at the `TapGestureRecognizer`. In [this post](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/gestures/tap/) is described how you can use it. You can apply it to virtually any control.

For example if you would style a `Label` to look like a button, you would add a double tap recognizer on it like this:

```
<Label Text="Tap me, I double dare you">
    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer
                Tapped="OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped"
                NumberOfTapsRequired="2" />
  </Label.GestureRecognizers>
</Label>
```

Of course you need to have an event called `OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped` in your code behind. But because of the value in the `NumberOfTapsRequired` property, you will need a double tap to activate it.

If you prefer code, this would be the counterpart:

```
var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
tapGestureRecognizer.NumberOfTapsRequired = 2;
tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += (s, e) => {
    // handle the tap
};
label.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);
```

Comment: That's useful, but I forgot to mention that I want to have both Tap and DoubleTap events wired to the same button. Using your solution I can wire the DoubleTap only.

Comment: To be more explicit: using your solution when I wire both Tap and DoubleTap, Tap interferes with DoubleTap (because a Tap will always occur before a DoubleTap).

Comment: I must say that sounds kind of counterintuitive, but if that is really what you want you should implement some kind of delay mechanism. When a single tap occurs what a little bit to see if a double tap happened after that and cancel the single tap.

Comment: I did this with javascript using the window timeout to wait for a second tap within a very short time interval: if a second tap happens during the interval then execute DoubleTap, otherwise execute Tap. My guess is that is how a TapGestureRecognizer with NumberOfTapsRequired="2" works, except that it swallows single taps. I don't quite know how to achieve the same in Xamarin Forms.

Answer (score 0):

ViewModel.cs:

```cs
private bool _isClicked = true;
public bool IsClicked
{
  get { return _isClicked = true; }
  set { _isClicked = true = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
}
```

View.xaml:

```html
<Button Text="Click!" IsEnabled="{Binding IsClicked}" />
```

Method (in ViewModel.cs):

```cs
public void MyMethod()
{
  IsClicked = false;
    
  // Your code
  IsClicked = true;
}
```