# Extend Label control - adding a Click event handler

Tags: c#, event-handling, xamarin.forms, extend

I need a control that can respond to both single click / tap and double click / tap. I found out I cannot use TapGestureRecognizer if I want to handle both single and double clicks / taps. So, I am trying to extend a Label control, adding a Click event handler. I tried the following code, but the event does not fire. Any suggestions? Thanks!

`in LabelClickable.cs:
    ...
    public class LabelClickable : Label
    {
        public event EventHandler Clicked;
        public virtual void OnClicked()
        {
            Clicked?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
    ...

in MainPage.XAML:
    ...
    <local:LabelClickable Text="0" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
    ...

and in MainPage.Xaml.cs:
    ...
    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //do something;
    }
    ...`

Comment: Shouldn't it be the TGR tapped event handler instead? Also, I have had more success adding TGR in code than XAML.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what TGR means. Also, the Forms.Label control I am trying to extend does not have a 'Clicked' event. If I succeed adding it then it would be a new event altogether on the extended control only, so I guess it does not matter what the name of that event is? I also tried to hook the event handler in code without success.

Comment: To add to all that, I can see the extended control being created (I've put a breakpoint in the constructor), and on the main page I can get the extended control using FindByName. Everything seems to be alright, the code compiles and runs, it's just that the event does not fire.

Comment: Sorry, was on my phone. By TGR I meant TapGestureRecognizer. From your question, it seemed like you intend to use TapGestureRecognizer so the extended control can recognize either single or double tap. I'll try to dig up some code here shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the complete working solution (thanks for the suggestions Jason!):

```
public class LabelClickable: Label
{
    public LabelClickable()
    {
        TapGestureRecognizer singleTap = new TapGestureRecognizer()
        {
            NumberOfTapsRequired = 1
        };
        TapGestureRecognizer doubleTap = new TapGestureRecognizer()
        {
            NumberOfTapsRequired = 2
        };
        this.GestureRecognizers.Add(singleTap);
        this.GestureRecognizers.Add(doubleTap);
        singleTap.Tapped += Label_Clicked;
        doubleTap.Tapped += Label_Clicked;
    }

    private static int clickCount;

    private void Label_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (clickCount < 1)
        {
            TimeSpan tt = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 250);
            Device.StartTimer(tt, ClickHandle);
        }
        clickCount++;
    }

    bool ClickHandle()
    {
        if (clickCount > 1)
        {
            Minus1();
        }
        else
        {
            Plus1();
        }
        clickCount = 0;
        return false;
    }

    private void Minus1()
    {
        int value = Convert.ToInt16(Text) - 1;
        if (value < 0)
            value = 0;
        Text = value.ToString();
    }

    private void Plus1()
    {
        Text = (Convert.ToInt16(Text) + 1).ToString();
    }
}
```

Usage on MainPage.xaml:

```
<local:LabelClickable Text="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="Transparent" FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
```

Nothing else is required on MainPage.xaml.cs.

Works like a charm for both single and double taps! The result is a clickable label displaying a counter; the counter increments on a single tap and decrements on a double tap.

Answer (score 1):

```
TappedGestureRecognizer sng = new TappedGestureRecognizer();
TappedGestureRecognizer dbl = new TappedGestureRecognizer();
dbl.NumberOfTapsRequired = 2;
sng.Tapped += OnSingleTap;
dbl.Tapped += OnDoubleTap;

// assuming you're within a Control's context
this.GestureRecognizers.Add(sng);
this.GestureRecognizers.Add(dbl);

protected void OnSingleTap(object sender, EventArgs e) {
}

protected void OnDoubleTap(object sender, EventArgs e) {
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I did try it but it does not work because in the case of a double tap event both TapGestureRecognizer fire, first the single tap, then the double tap. That makes sense, since a double tap will always has a single tap. I need them to be exclusive. I don't think this can be achieved with TapGestureRecognizer because the way they are implemented. I know how to implement click and double-click events to be mutually exclusive: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42911926/handling-button-gesture-for-both-single-and-double-click-tap

Comment: you could try tracking the timestamps of the taps and if a single tap registers in some window before a double tap, then ignore it.

Comment: yes, that's what I am doing, have a look at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42911926/handling-button-gesture-for-both-single-and-double-click-tap

Comment: I could use a Forms.Button, except that I need to have the button text aligned in the top right corner, and the Forms.Button does not allow for text alignment. So I could either extend a Label by adding a click event (hence this question), or extend a button to allow for custom text alignment.

Comment: I don't understand what about the solution posted in the other question is inadequate?

Comment: The other solution works for handling mutually exclusive single and double taps. I don't have a problem with that. The question here is how do I extend a Label by adding a Click event to it.

Comment: a Label doesn't have any inherent concept of "Click" - that's why you use TappedGestureRecognizer.  When the tap event(s) fire, you can then call the external Click handler if it's assigned.